# Перестали работать webSockets

Tags: nginx, websocket

Вчера решили включить технологию ngix для ускорения работы, и после её включения все пошло по известному месту. На сайте отключились сокеты и регулярно выдаются ошибки в консоль, которые приложу ниже. Выключали ngix и ошибка никуда не пропала, Кто знает в чем ошибка? Если нужны какие-то файлы, то я приложу скрины.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего проблема в настройках `nginx`, что клиент не может достучаться до сокет сервера по адресу/порту

Comment: А как правильно нужно настроить этот самый ngix ?

Comment: Скорее всего из за не подписанного  или бесплатного сертификата, ибо вы используете `wss` (защищенный протокол). Уже сталкивался с подобным, `ws` работает, а `wss` нет, купили сертификат, внедрили подписку в коде и все заработало. Подробнее читайте в документации по сокетам.

Comment: А где купить этот самый сертификат? И как его включить?

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html